# Best way to dynamically set the selected option based on condition

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a `select` box that I generate for each element in an `array` using the `innerHTML` method in `Javascript`. I would like to have it so that depending on the value of x[1] a different option is selected for each row.

Basically x[1] represents a quantity of an item to be ordered and the purpose of the `select` box is to allow the user to adjust the quantity before confirming the order.

```
for(i = 0; i < productArray.length; i ++){
        item = productArray[i];
        var x = item.split(':');
        var row = ordertable.insertRow(i + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = x[0];
        cell2.innerHTML = x[1] + "<select>\n\
                    <option value='0'>0</option>\n\
                    <option value='1'>1</option>\n\
                    <option value='2'>2</option>\n\
                    <option value='3'>3</option>\n\
                      </select>";
        cell3.innerHTML =       "<input type='button' value='Delete' class='deleteBtn'/>"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
var arr = ["<option value='0'>0</option>",
           "<option value='1'>1</option>",
           "<option value='2'>2</option>",
           "<option value='3'>3</option>"];

var i = x[1];
arr[i] = arr[i].substring(0, 8) + " selected='selected' " + arr[i].substring(8);


cell2.innerHTML = "<select>\n" + arr.join("\n") + "</select>";
```

Comment: Yes but the problem when I do this is that all the boxes are set to that option, I would like to have a different value on each box. For example if x[1] is equal to 3 then I want the value 3 selected, if x[1] is equal to 2 then I want the value 2 selected.

Comment: @Javacadabra use an `if` condition ?

Comment: I suppose I could do this, I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way, because If I have a large number of `select options` then the code would be quite long.

Comment: @Javacadabra Ok, I am thinking about it.

Comment: Thank you, I do not have a lot of experience with `Javascript` so trying to do things in the most efficient and effective way

Comment: @Javacadabra See console and on prompt, enter number in range `0-3`

Comment: I like this solution, although I am wondering if @simcha solution is simpler??

Comment: Actually no, I think your solution is the best answer as it requires no if statement

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an `if` statement.

```
cell2.innerHTML = x[1] + "<select>";
cell2.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML + "<option value='0'" + (x[1] == "0" ? "selected='selected'" : "") + ">0</option>";
cell2.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML + "<option value='1'" + (x[1] == "1" ? "selected='selected'" : "") + ">1</option>";
cell2.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML + "<option value='2'" + (x[1] == "2" ? "selected='selected'" : "") + ">2</option>";
cell2.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML + "<option value='3'" + (x[1] == "3" ? "selected='selected'" : "") + ">3</option>";
cell2.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML + "</select>";
```

Another "hack" way to do it with **one line** is just to add the following code:

```
 cell2.innerHTML.replace("<option value='" + x[1] + "'>" + x[1] + "</option>","<option value='" + x[1] + "' selected='selected'>" + x[1] + "</option>");
```

So the final code will look as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < productArray.length; i ++){
        item = productArray[i];
        var x = item.split(':');
        var row = ordertable.insertRow(i + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = x[0];
        cell2.innerHTML = x[1] + "<select>\n\
                    <option value='0'>0</option>\n\
                    <option value='1'>1</option>\n\
                    <option value='2'>2</option>\n\
                    <option value='3'>3</option>\n\
                      </select>";
        cell2.innerHTML.replace("<option value='" + x[1] + "'>" + x[1] + "</option>","<option value='" + x[1] + "' selected='selected'>" + x[1] + "</option>");
        cell3.innerHTML =       "<input type='button' value='Delete' class='deleteBtn'/>"
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this `.replace` method is indeed nice. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could add a unique id to the `<select>` then at the end of the loop say

```
document.getElementById("mySelectId").selectedIndex = x[1];
```

Note, the index is base zero

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use a for loop and an if statement to achieve what you are trying to do, try the following:

```
var content = x[1]+"<select>";
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    content += "<option value='"+i+"'"+((x[1] == i) ? " selected='selected'" : "")+">"+i+"</option>";
}
content += "</select>";
```

and change your cell2 to be

```
cell2.innerHTML = content;
```

Hope that is what you're looking for!